# Javascript file isn't appending to a filtered list

Tags: javascript

As the title reads, my javascript file won't append to a filtered list via a random generator function, for context it's being built in replit so perhaps its just a buggy bit of software on replits end, though I'm certain I've done something wrong and can't for the life of me figure out what. The main idea for this project is to have it randomly select an item from a list, append it to an empty list, then pass that string to an HTML textarea tag to be displayed as text.

Code in question:

```
var LowercaseList = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"];

var NumList = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0"];

var SpecialCharList = ["`","~","!","#","$","%","^","&","*","_","-","+","=","<",">","?","/"];

// Letter list ID's since I couldn't figure out how to run this using a database
var LetterIDList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26];

// Number list ID's since I couldn't figure out how to run this using a database
var NumIDList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

// Special character list ID's since I couldn't figure out how to run this using a database
var SpecialID = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17];

// Filtered Lists
var UpperFiltered = [];
var LowerFiltered = [];
var NumFiltered = [];
var SpecialFiltered = [];

// Global declarations of random number variables to grab values from intial lists
var UpperGenVariable;
var LowerGenVariable;
var NumGenVariable;
var SpecialGenVariable;

// Creates a basic password with 2 of each kind of character
function Basic () {
  for (var i = 1; i < 2; i++) {
    UppercaseGenerate();
  }
  for (var i = 1; i < 2; i++) {
    LowercaseGenerate();
  }
  for (var i = 1; i < 2; i++) {
    NumGenerate();
  }
  for (var i = 1; i < 2; i++) {
    SpecialGenerate();
  }
};
let passwordGen = document.getElementById("PasswordDisplay")

function UppercaseGenerate () {
  var UpperFiltered = [];
  UpperGenVariable = Math.random(0, LetterIDList.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < LetterIDList.length - 1; i++) {
    if (LetterIDList[i] == UpperGenVariable) {
      appendItem(UpperFiltered, UppercaseList[i]);
    }
  };
  console.log(UpperFiltered);
  passwordGen.value = UpperFiltered
};
```

HTML textarea code:

```
<label style = "color:white;" for="PasswordDisplay">Your generated password ----></label>
     <textarea  readonly id="PasswordDisplay" name="PasswordDisplay" rows="10" cols="50">
       Please select a password complexity setting
     </textarea>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed how you generate the random number.
Also added the `UppercaseList`, added `i <= 2` rather then `i < 2` in the cycles so the yould really run 2 times, added `+=` to `passwordGen.value += UpperFiltered` so the value would add up.
I guess that is it.

```js
var UppercaseList = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"];

var LowercaseList = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"];

var NumList = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0"];

var SpecialCharList = ["`","~","!","#","$","%","^","&","*","_","-","+","=","<",">","?","/"];

// Letter list ID's since I couldn't figure out how to run this using a database
var LetterIDList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26];

// Number list ID's since I couldn't figure out how to run this using a database
var NumIDList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

// Special character list ID's since I couldn't figure out how to run this using a database
var SpecialID = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17];

// Filtered Lists
var UpperFiltered = [];
var LowerFiltered = [];
var NumFiltered = [];
var SpecialFiltered = [];

// Global declarations of random number variables to grab values from intial lists
var UpperGenVariable;
var LowerGenVariable;
var NumGenVariable;
var SpecialGenVariable;

// Creates a basic password with 2 of each kind of character
function Basic () {
  for (var i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
    UppercaseGenerate();
  }
  for (var i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
    LowercaseGenerate();
  }
  for (var i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
    NumGenerate();
  }
  for (var i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
    SpecialGenerate();
  }
};

let passwordGen = document.getElementById("PasswordDisplay")

function UppercaseGenerate() {
  var UpperFiltered = [];
  UpperGenVariable = Math.floor(Math.random() * LetterIDList.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < LetterIDList.length; i++) {
    if (LetterIDList[i] == UpperGenVariable) {
      UpperFiltered.push(UppercaseList[i]);
    }
  };
  passwordGen.value += UpperFiltered
};
```

Comment: thank you, I'll try running it and see if it works
edit: uppercase list was there, just didn't get copied I guess

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you

Comment: @McSquidy You are welcome. Usually the correct answers are [marked accordingly as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), which will endorse the answerer (and yourself a bit), help the others to understand that the question has been answered and easily find an answer, when there are a lot of them. But it is not mandatory.